# Why is my ajax partial view rendering on a new page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, view, partial-views

Spent ages trying to fix this and getting nowhere.
Basically when the action link is clicked I want the div to be updated with the values which are showing up on the new page but cannot seem to fix the problem.
Here is my code:

```
@*@model PagedList.IPagedList<S00117372CA3.Product>*@
@*@model Tuple<PagedList.IPagedList<S00117372CA3.Product>, IEnumerable<S00117372CA3.Order>>*@
@model S00117372CA3.Controllers.ProductViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="searchResult">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products.First().ProductName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products.First().Supplier.CompanyName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products.First().Category.CategoryName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products.First().QuantityPerUnit)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products.First().UnitPrice)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products.First().UnitsInStock)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products.First().UnitsOnOrder)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products.First().ReorderLevel)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products.First().Discontinued)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Products) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Supplier.CompanyName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.CategoryName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuantityPerUnit)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitPrice)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitsInStock)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitsOnOrder)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReorderLevel)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Discontinued)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ProductID }) |
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ProductID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "searchResult", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ProductID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

<div>
    Page @(Model.Products.PageCount < Model.Products.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.Products.PageNumber) of @Model.Products.PageCount
    @if (Model.Products.HasPreviousPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("<<", "Index", new { page = 1})
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "Index", new {page = Model.Products.PageNumber - 1})
    }
    else{
     @:<<
     @Html.Raw(" ");
        @:< Prev   
    }

    @if (Model.Products.HasNextPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Next >", "Index", new {page = Model.Products.PageNumber + 1})
        @Html.Raw(" "); 
        @Html.ActionLink(">>", "Index", new {page = Model.Products.PageCount})
    }
    else{
     @:Next >
     @Html.Raw(" ")
@:>>   
    }
</div>

<div id="searchResult">

</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your folder structure.. there is a file called `_ViewStart.cshtml`. This file provides initial setup for your views within the given area.

This file probably has:

```
@{
    Layout = "path/to/layout/here.cshtml";
}
```

In which case.. all views you render with `return View()` will utilize this.

You have two options.. either:

a)

```
return PartialView();
```

.. from your action method. Or..

b) In your partial view:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

I took a guess at your problem.. your question isn't particularly easy to understand.

Comment: My Action Method finishes like this: return PartialView("_Orders", model); so I'm assuming thats what you mean in part a

Comment: Try option b then. It's one of them :)

Comment: Tried option b there too. Still opening a new page. This is really making my head hurt :/ Any other ideas?

Comment: Wait.. so that ajax actionlink isnt being ajaxy?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you only need to install `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax` via Nuget and add the reference into the view like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
```

(Or you can do so the bundle)

This is needed because microsoft didn't add this by default in MVC 5.